# Using same method FindAsync but different return value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the same method to call the **FindAsync** method in db, one return the reference of db, but another one is not. Thanks!

```
Session s = await db.Sessions.FindAsync(SessionID);
```

returns

> (Session)s{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Session_BFA80795AACB5D49C975D9F7A4CCB06C3EC8305DE4794CDBC821344056545BE9}

```
PersonnelInfo i = await db.PersonnelInfoes.FindAsync(PersonnelInfoID);
```

returns

> {cc_cook.Models.PersonnelInfo}

Comment: You are using the `FindAsync` method on two completely different types/classes. Why would you expect them to return the same result? And what do you mean by "reference of db"? The first one returns an object of type `Session` and the other one returns an object of type `PersonnelInfo`.

Comment: From what you typed, first one returns a session instance and the second one returns a PersonnelInfo instance; thus they are bound to return different values.

Comment: Actually I want to update two navigation properties of a class,  I do the assignments as following:

class.session = s;
class.personnelinfo = i;

the "s" success to attach to the class but the "i" make an insertion statement to the database and it made a primary key conflict error.